# Symbols in dylib, Works with gcc-4.0 not in gcc-4.2 (OSX-default)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, exc-bad-access, dylib

i'v got an dynamic-Lib which i build with

```
OBJECTS=keys.o etc2.o foo.o
$(CC) -DSYS_MACOSX  -g -fPIC -flat_namespace -L. -lpthread  -Wl,-flat_namespace -dynamiclib  -shared -o libmylib.dylib $(OBJECTS)
```

My test progam links with this library

```
$(CC) -DSYS_MACOSX  -g -fPIC testmain.c -o testmain -I. -flat_namespace -L. -lpthread  -lmylib
```

When CC=gcc-4.2 I get following error in gdb, when I try to access const symbols in libmylib.dylib:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000112dd0
0x0000000100004ec7 in extractKeyFromList (keyList=0x112dd0, key=0x1002001e0 "Adresse1.aName1") at keys.c:148
```

The programm works, with:

- gcc-4.0 on SnowLeopard
- gcc-4.3.2 on Debian i386
- gcc-4.1.2 for arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi

Update: Here is some debug-output main=main loadKeyList=function in Lib

GCC 4.0:

```
main:            sizeof KeyList =  149480
loadKeyList:     sizeof KeyList =  149480
loadKeyList:     list at 0xfe88c
loadKeyList:     sizeof list =  149480
loadKeyList:     list->count 3086
main:            sizeof handle->keyList = 149480
main:            handle->keyList at 0xfe88c
main:            handle->keyList->count 3086
```

GCC4.2

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: keyextractor -k Adresse1.aName1
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++. done
main:            sizeof KeyList =  166088
loadKeyList:     sizeof KeyList =  166088
loadKeyList:     list at 0x112dd0
loadKeyList:     sizeof list =  166088
loadKeyList:     list->count 3086
main:            sizeof handle->keyList = 166088
main:            handle->keyList at 0x112dd0

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000112dd0
0x0000000100001940 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff5fbfefb8) at keyextractor.c:110
110     printf("main:            handle->keyList->count %i\n", handle->keyList->count);
(gdb)
```

The Struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _KeyList {
    int count;
    Key keys[4152];
} KeyList;
```

Update 2: This works in gcc-4.2 from main

```
printf("KEYMAP.keyList[5] at 0x%x count = %i\n", &KEYMAP.keyList[5], KEYMAP.keyList[5].count);
Output: KEYMAP.keyList[5] at 0x112dd0 count = 3086
```

That's the same adress like pointer handle->keyList!

KEYMAP looks like:

```
typedef struct _KeyMapList {
    int count;
    KeyList keyList[];
} KeyMapList;

const KeyMapList KEYMAP = {
  .count = 6,
  .keyList = {
   { ... }, { .... },
   { ... }, { .... },
   { ... }, { .count=3086, keys.... }
   }
};
```

So whats the problem with gcc-4.2?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging the problem ? E.g. run the program under gdb, do a backtrace when it crashes, and work from there ?

Comment: yes ... it crashes, when it tries to access a member of a struct.
148  int last = keyList->count;
with the gdb-Error above

Comment: I think we need to see some code to help with this - possibly you are getting Undefined behaviour which can do different things on different compilers

Comment: i've updated the example.
Basically i get a pointer to the Struct KeyList from the function in the dylib.
list and handle->keyList have the same adress, but accessing the ->count-Member is only allowed from inside the dylib function in gcc4.2. gcc4.0 allows both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program failed on Linux-x86_64, too

But the real answer is: you should listen to gcc warnings and compile with -Wall

```
 keyextractor.c:114: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

This warning was in the line, where I called a function from the Lib, **without** #include-ing the respective Header-File.
Without function-declartion it worked:

- i386-architecture as shared lib and static
- x86_64-architecture only static

So, after including the right header-file, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

ok .. it seems not to be a problem with gcc.

It's a problem with the x86_64-Architecture.
Building with "-arch i386" solves the problem with gcc4.2.

I still don't know, why it doesn't work with x86_64.
Both binary and dylib are x86_64:

```
libmylib.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
keyextractor:   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```